# Airbyte: Cannot discover schema on MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, airbyte

On a brand new Airbyte installation, with a source of MongoDB and a destination of MySQL, the "Discovering schema" phase of setting up a connection fails with:

```
Internal message: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 40353 (Location40353): 'Invalid $project :: caused by :: FieldPath must not end with a '.'.' on server 192.168.86.20:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Invalid $project :: caused by :: FieldPath must not end with a '.'.", "code": 40353, "codeName": "Location40353"}
Failure type: system_error
```

Presumably this means that the query that Airbyte has generated has something weird and broken in it, but how do I find out what that is and how do I resolve it?

Comment: What's the FilePath? The error points to that.

Invalid $project :: caused by :: FieldPath must not end with a '.'.

Comment: @AleksandarBasara sorry, i dont understand - what file path?  it's a docker install, connecting over IP to mongo

Comment: Hi @johnspackman . You can find the solution you're looking for at https://groups.google.com/g/mongodb-user/c/qotO6gtKn9Q/m/wdhlcyvCGgAJ. In other way, you should add more elements about your code and/or context. I guess that some field path in your MongoDB is ending up with a '.' and Airbyte doesn't allow the schema of the source with such field path.